# Вызов нескольких методов

Tags: ооп, php

Привет. Помогите мне понять, как мне вызвать методы из класса PHP таким образом:

```
$class->test_method('param1')->test_method2('param2');
```

Иначе приходится делать не совсем удобно:

```
$class->test_method('param1');
$class->test_method2('param2');
```

Comment: @stereoflo, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 8):

Эта штука называется Fluent Interface и зачастую подвергается критике из-за пары аспектов. Хотя, как можно видеть по многочисленным примерам, используется много где, и библиотеки от этого не поумирали.

```
class FluentInterfaceImplementation
{
    public function methodA()
    {
        // ...
        return $this;
    }
    public function methodB()
    {
        // ...
        return $this;
    }
}

$object = new FluentInterfaceImplementation;
$object->methodA()->methodB();
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как в PHP, но в общей концепции ООП, чтобы такое делать

```
test_method('param1')
```

должен возвращать вам

```
$class
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополню Etki

```
class Message
{

    private $text;

    function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }
}

class Inbox
{
    function getLastMessage()
    {
        //Выбор последнего сообщения
        return $message; //Объект типа Message
    }
}
```

Тогда можно будет писать что-то типа этого:

```
$inbox = new Inbox();
$inbox->getLastMessage() //получение объекта сообщения из объекта почтового ящика
    ->getText() //получение текста
```

Т.е. если метод возвращает объект - можно обращаться к методам возвращаемого объекта по цепочке.