# Функция как объект

Tags: php

Как реализовывается следующая последовательность?

```
class()->method();
```

или

```
class()->variable;
```

Такие плюшки встречаются в фреймворке Laravel 5 но как реализовать самому пока ума не приложу. Перекапывать исходники фреймворка нет времени что бы найти ноги...

Может кто сталкивался с подобной реализацией прошу подсказать где почитать или хотя бы натолкнуть на путь истинный.

**UPD:**

Суть вопрос не заключается в вызове методов или переменных класса посредством

`$class = new someclass();`

и дальнейшее его использование...

Поясню глубже, в Laravel 5 к примеру View можно использовать так

`View::share('var', 'value');`

а можно и так

`view()->share('var', 'value');`

Вот собственно меня и интересует как реализовывается это все чудо и выглядит оно вот так

**view()->share('var', 'value');**

Пожалуйста не отвечайте на вопрос по примеру @JILeXanDR

**UPD2:**

я дичайше удивлен но действительно работает

```
class view
{
    function share()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}

function view()
{
    return new view;
}

view()->share();
```

Благодарю @Sergiks, вопрос исчерпан!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов нескольких методов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/379689/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: если метод возвращает `return $this` то после вызова метода можно обратиться к другим методам объекта. Если вместо `$this` возвращать другой объект, то, соответственно, можно вызывать методы этого объекта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никакой магии. `view()` – обычная глобальная функция-помощник (helper), определена в конце файла [`helpers.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php):

```
/**
 * Get the evaluated view contents for the given view.
 *
 * @param  string  $view
 * @param  array   $data
 * @param  array   $mergeData
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
function view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
{
    $factory = app('Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory');
    if (func_num_args() === 0) {
        return $factory;
    }
    return $factory->make($view, $data, $mergeData);
}
```